# Add background color to list item bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-color

I have an ordered list (a, b, c...) and want to make the background color of the actual bullets (a, b, c...) a different color.  How would I style this?  The list-type property seems to only change the bullets, not give them added styling.  I want to maintain they type="a" structure of the list and simply add a background color to each letter.

Also...can someone share with me how to center the bullets or flush them to one side? Currently, they look a little out of line.

Comment: It would really help people if you put some sample code in your post or better and your html and css to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and link to it.

Comment: Check the demo of mine http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Hj8Nn/ , for alpha letters, just replace `content: counter(index)` with `content: counter(index, lower-alpha)`

Answer (score 6):

Using @kingkong's comment above, you can do something like this:

```
ul > li:before {  
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    content: counter(index, lower-alpha);
    counter-increment:index;
}
li:first-child {
    counter-reset:index;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZsQY/

Comment: Definitely the better answer, was just looking into counters when I realised OP wanted lower-alpha.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ue6nu/2/

The default lower-alpha will be preserved even when :before is not supported.

```
ul {font: 0.85em Arial;margin:0;}
li {
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    position:relative;
}
li:first-child {
    counter-reset:index;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(index, lower-alpha) '.';
    counter-increment:index;
    background: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1.3em;
    z-index:10;
    display:inline-block;
    width:1em;
    color: red;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style them with the nth-child selector and pseudo elements.

```
ul li:before {  
    content: "• ";
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UumDL/)

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to change the background-color, not the color of the bullet. Also, why are you only applying it to one? And that demo page is irrelevant to this question

Comment: The default list-style:lower-alpha adds also the dot at the end. It seems content: counter(index, lower-alpha) does not add the dot?