# html: <ol> list-style background color

Tags: html, css

I would like to create this: http://www.kephost.com/images/2015/07/15/ol-color-picture.png

[image]
The easiest way would be, if i could use span for only the "list-style elements"(1. 2. 3. etc...):

```
<ol>
   <span style="background-color:Aqua><li></span>..."text"...</li>
</ol>
```

But that doesn't do anything with the "list-style elements" (1. 2. 3. etc...)
Is there any solution? I need exactly 5 choosable background-color for the list-style elements: yellow, red, orange, green, aqua. Thx for answering.

Comment: The HTML is invalid.

Comment: The correct way to implement this would be using a css counter instead of the regular list-style-elements. See my answer below.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552988/add-background-color-to-list-item-bullet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to fix your invalid HTML first. The only direct child elements allowed in `<ol>` are `<li>`. Wrapping `<li>` in a `<span>` is not only invalid, you also have disobeyed the rule of well-formedness, which basically states that when you nest elements, the outer element must be closed *after* the inner element.

But anyway, it's not necessary here to use additional markup, just the `<li>`will work fine as long as you place the proper css class in it:

```css
.bg-yellow::before {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bg-red::before {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-green::before {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-orange::before {
  background-color: orange;
}
.bg-aqua::before {
  background-color: aqua;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: myOrderedListItemsCounter;
}
ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
  counter-increment: myOrderedListItemsCounter;
  content: counter(myOrderedListItemsCounter)".";
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="bg-yellow">Yellow here</li>
  <li class="bg-red">Red here</li>
  <li class="bg-orange">Orange here</li>
  <li class="bg-green">Green here</li>
  <li class="bg-aqua">Aqua here</li>
</ol>
```

If you have no experience with css counters as of now, here's some more information on it:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: He wants the numbers colored, not the text.

Comment: I realized that after I had posted the initial answer and immediately adapted the answer using a css counter.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:

```css
ul > li:before {  
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    content: counter(index, decimal);
    counter-increment:index;
}
li:first-child {
    counter-reset:index;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li:nth-child(1):before {  
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul > li:nth-child(2):before {  
    background-color: blue;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3):before {  
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>..text..</li>
    <li>..text..</li>
    <li>..text..</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using pseudo elements and relative positioning

```css
li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -24px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
li.red:before {
  background-color: red;
}
li.blue:before {
  background-color: blue;
}
li.aqua:before {
  background-color: aqua;
}
li.yellow:before {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="red">First item</li>
  <li class="blue">Second item</li>
  <li class="aqua">Third item</li>
  <li class="yellow">One more</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This will not work for larger font-sizes, and it will also fail with e.g. three-digit-ordering numbers, like you can easily get them in a top 100 chartlist for example, or in an address list. it's better to implement this using css counters.

Answer (score 1):

With some CSS3 tricks, you can get a result that is pretty close to what you are seeking, though I don't believe you can get an exact match.

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j4Lrewkd/

You can see some of the tricks used: 
`list-style-type: none;` Removes the numbers in the ordered list.

The `::before` pseudo-selector allows us to replace them with style-able elements.

Finally, the `:nth-of-type()` selector allows us to style each element seperately.

Answer (score 0):

here do this. here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d7tp553z/1/

```
<ol style="background-color: blue;">
   <li style="background-color: white;">..."text"...</li>
</ol>
```