# Is it possible to add background color to list item marker in html without :before, counter-increment etc

Tags: html, css

I am asking this because I need to convert html to pdf by using `iText` and it doesn't support `counter-increment`.
So is there any way to add background-color to list item marker without using generating markers by using `before` selector and `counter-increment` ?

Comment: You want to set the background color, or the color of the list item marker? The background-color question seems to be answered [by the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31438731/215552). For the color of the marker itself, [some of the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470214/215552) make no use of `counter-increment`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i want to set bgcolor. and the link you gave uses css counter. only the last answer is not using counter but it uses before selector and it is not supported by iText :(